# How do i know if ActiveMQ is using my activemq.xml?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jms, activemq-classic

I am creating an embedded ActiveMQ in Tomcat by the below context.xml. It specifies the config xml location in the broker url `brokerURL="vm://localhost?brokerConfig=xbean:activemq.xml"`.

I have put the `activemq.xml` at the base of my WAR file (so right *next* to WEB-INF in the WAR). Will it be found there?

***MyWAR.war

     WEB-INF/

           beans.xml

     activemq.xml***

My context.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>

    <!-- JMS Factory and Queue -->
    <Resource auth="Container"
            name="jms/ConnectionFactory"
            type="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"
            description="JMS Connection Factory"
            factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory"
            brokerURL="vm://localhost?brokerConfig=xbean:activemq.xml"
            brokerName="MyBroker"
            useEmbeddedBroker="true"
            trustAllPackages="true"
            persistent="true"
    />

    <Resource auth="Container"
            name="jms/MyQueue"
            type="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue"
            description="Downtime Event JMS queue"
            factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory"
            physicalName="MyQueue"
            persistent="true"
    />

    <Resource auth="Container"
            name="jms/MyQueueRetry"
            type="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue"
            description="Downtime Event JMS queue"
            factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory"
            physicalName="MyQueueRetry"
            persistent="true"
    />

</Context>
```

**EDIT: my updated activemq.xml**:

```
<beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <bean id="ioExceptionHandler" class="org.apache.activemq.util.DefaultIOExceptionHandler">
        <property name="ignoreAllErrors"><value>true</value></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- MySql DataSource Sample Setup -->
    <bean id="mysql-ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/activemq"/>
        <property name="username" value="testuser"/>
        <property name="password" value="password"/>
        <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <broker
            xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
            persistent="true"
            ioExceptionHandler="#ioExceptionHandler"
            useShutdownHook="true"
            useJmx="false"
            brokerName="EventBroker"
    >
        <persistenceAdapter>
            <jdbcPersistenceAdapter dataSource="#mysql-ds" />
        </persistenceAdapter>
    </broker>
</beans>
```

I also tried both of the following:

`brokerURL="vm://localhost?brokerConfig=xbean:classpath:activemq.xml"`

(And putting it in WEB-INF)
`brokerURL="vm://localhost?brokerConfig=xbean:classpath:WEB-INF/activemq.xml"`

It never uses MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Partially from the help of @Matt_Pavlovich)

You have to use the `classpath:` key under the xbeans AND it has to be in a directory that can be found on the WAR classpath (e.g. META-INF):

```
brokerURL="vm://localhost?brokerConfig=xbean:classpath:META-INF/activemq.xml"
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple ways..

Crank up the logging of org.apache.activemq to DEBUG or TRACE

Add an additional  entry on an open port 61618.. confirm it is listening using netstat.

Also, you can connect up to JMX of the running JVM process and see the org.apache.activemq JMX beans present.

A couple references:

- [ActiveMQ+Camel+Tomcat](http://camel.apache.org/activemq-camel-tomcat.html)
- [ActiveMQ xbean uri](http://activemq.apache.org/broker-xbean-uri.html)

Comment: Thank you, do you know how I can make it read the activemq.xml in my WAR file? It doesn't seem to be using it.

Comment: Have you tried using xbean:classpath:activemq.xml ?

Comment: No, I'll try that and let you know if it works, thanks!

Comment: Don Rhummy I edited my answer w/ a couple links to review as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not using the file. I added a `jdbcPersistenceAdapter` and it still uses kahadb and doesn't create anything in MySQL. Any ideas?

Comment: I got it to work! You were right to use classpath, but it has to be in META-INF to be found.

Comment: Glad to here =)